# How to add ruler configuration to Loki stack with Helm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, grafana-loki

I just want to add the ruler configuration, so I can have alerts for Loki metrics.
However that seems quite a challenge.

That is my configuration for Grafana Loki:

```
replicaCount: 1
affinity: {}

loki:
  read:
    extraVolumeMounts:
      - name: loki-rules-config
        mountPath: /etc/loki/rules
      - name: loki-rules-config
        configMap:
          name: loki-rules-config
  ruler:
    enabled: true
    config:
      rule_path: /etc/loki/rules
      storage:
        type: filesystem
        config:
          directory: /var/loki/rules

  service:
    type: ClusterIP
  config:
    query_scheduler:
      max_outstanding_requests_per_tenant: 4096
    limits_config:
      split_queries_by_interval: 24h
      max_query_parallelism: 100
    frontend:
      max_outstanding_per_tenant: 4096

ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx-internal"
  hosts:
    - "dada.dada-dada.dada.de"

fluent-bit:
  enabled: false

promtail:
  enabled: true
  serviceMonitor:
    enabled: true
```

I tried manually adding the configmap, and then referencing it inside the chart, doesn't work. It just doesn't pick it up. Has anyone already implement Loki stack chart and made it work?

Answer (score 1):

[Official loki chart](https://github.com/grafana/loki/tree/main/production/helm/loki) can be used for both single binary deployment and simple scalable deployment (SSD).
By default it runs SSD with 3 replicas of each role (3 readers, 3 writers and 3 backend services).
Nothing stops you from running SSD as following:

```yaml
write:
  replicas: 1
read:
  replicas: 1
backend:
  replicas: 1
```

Using this in `values.yaml`, you will get single replica for each role.

Moreover you can use single binary deployment as following:

```yaml
write:
  replicas: 0
read:
  replicas: 0
backend:
  replicas: 0
singleBinary:
  replicas: 1
```

And you will get one statefulset for single binary handling all roles at once and deployment for gateway (which is used for accessing Loki from outside or from cluster).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Loki stack Helm chart values](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/loki-stack/values.yaml), I don't see any reference to the ruler. I suspect it may not be supported.

The recommended helm chart for Loki is the [officially supported one](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/setup/install/helm/). Looking at [its values](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/setup/install/helm/reference/#helm-chart-values), there's is a `loki.rulerConfig` field you can configure.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your answer. But the Loki only configures a lot of unnecessary pods, I just want to have 1 pod for everything similar to Loki stack with only 1 replication. Would you help me simulate the same case scenario? If that works I would just go away from Loki stack.